# SQL data not returning based on date

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have a column in my database which stores a date as date/time. I have a SQL query to select all records where the date matches the one in the query, but it is not returning any data.

```
select Name,Dateadded from table
```

this returns results like

```
Bob Smith  2009-12-11 09:35:53.000
```

I changed my query to be the below and no results are returned.

```
select Name,Dateadded from table where dateadded = '2009-12-11'
```

I tried the converting to date and still no luck, I have to enter in a date between query to get it working

```
SELECT
Name,  convert(varchar(10), Dateadded , 103)
FROM
table
```

can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? I have tried using 'like' and still does not work if I do 'between' two date ranges it works

Comment: which rdbms   you are using??

Comment: SQL  Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `datetime` to `date` in your `where` clause:

```
select Name,Dateadded
from table 
where Convert(date, dateadded) = '2009-12-11'
```

Comment: thank you I moved the convert from the select statement to the where clause and it now work

Answer (score 3):

It may be like this:

```
WHERE Dateadded >= '2014-07-24' AND Dateadded < '2014-07-25'
WHERE Dateadded >= '2014-07-24' AND Dateadded < DATEADD(dd, 1, '2014-07-24')
```

or with convert:

```
WHERE convert(date,Dateadded) = '2014-07-24'
```

and also you can do something like that

```
WHERE DAY(Dateadded) = 24 AND MONTH(Dateadded) = 07 AND YEAR(Dateadded) = 2014
```

Comment: The second query is the correct way to go. Don't convert.

Answer (score 1):

Casting to `date` as in other answers will work. For performance, it may be better (depending on indexes) to use:

```
select Name,Dateadded 
from   [table] 
where  dateadded >= '2009-12-11'
   and dateadded < '2009-12-12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `=` only when you expect exact match. In your case you can use :

```
select Name,Dateadded from table where dateadded like '2009-12-11%'
```

Comment: I have tried like and wildcards and still does not work

Comment: Please keep in mind that `table` and `name` are reserved keywords.

Comment: Please, check out the comments in the link, that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
select Name,Dateadded from table where date(dateadded) = '2009-12-11'
```

as you are trying to match only date.

Note : after seeing comments , it seems you are using sql server 2012, above works in mysql not sure about sql server 2012

Answer (score 0):

The following codes will work:

```
SELECT Name,Dateadded FROM table WHERE Dateadded LIKE '2009-12-11%'
```

or

```
SELECT Name,Dateadded FROM table WHERE Dateadded >= '2009-12-11 00:00:00' AND Dateadded <= '2009-12-11 23:59:59'
```

or

```
SELECT Name,Dateadded FROM table WHERE Dateadded BETWEEN '2009-12-11 00:00:00' AND '2009-12-11 23:59:59'
```